# Discord.js Voice Channel with Slash Commands

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a Music Bot with the new Discord Slash Commands, but I don't know how to get the voice channel which the user is in.

With a normal Message-Command it's `message.member.voice.channel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `interaction.member` doesn't contain any voice information, i defined the voice channel as follows:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guild_id)
const member = guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id);
const voiceChannel = member.voice.channel;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer's code, I needed one extra line at the end.

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guild_id)
const member = guild.member(interaction.member.user.id)
const vchannel = member.voice.channel
vchannel.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Interaction#member`](https://github.com/devsnek/discord.js/blob/interactions/src/structures/Interaction.js#L61) which will return the member who sent the interaction if it was sent in a guild, or `null` if it was not sent in a guild.

Comment: But Interaction#member doesn't contain any voice information - correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: By the looks of the code and the JSDoc annotation it returns a valid `GuildMember` with all properties any other `GuildMember` would have ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: If it doesn't exist you could also try using [`GuildMember#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch) and then checking again, but other than that I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

```
const voice_channel_id = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id).voice.channelId
```

Comment: one line version of the accepted answer.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.